# Javascript ScrollTo apply event only to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling, scrollto

Problem: I got two divs with the same content and multipe anchors in there (scrollable), if u click the scrolling trigger button in one div, both div contents are scrolling, but only one (where clicked) should. 
How can I bind the event to the div where the trigger was clicked? Tried with $(this) but couldn't figure it out.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="tile_list_wrapper">
<div class="tile__list">
   <a class="quickmark" href="https://google.com" target="Google" ondrop="checkondrop();"><img src="../../images/add_icon.png"></a>
   <a class="quickmark" href="https://google.com" target="Google" ondrop="checkondrop();"><img src="../../images/add_icon.png"></a>
 <button class="tile__more">more </button>
</div> 
</div>

<div class="tile_list_wrapper">
<div class="tile__list">
   <a class="quickmark" href="https://google.com" target="Google" ondrop="checkondrop();"><img src="../../images/add_icon.png"></a>
   <a class="quickmark" href="https://google.com" target="Google" ondrop="checkondrop();"><img src="../../images/add_icon.png"></a>
 <button class="tile__more">more </button>
</div> 
</div>


<script>
var $quickmarks = $('.tile__list').children('a');
var $chScrollPositions = new Array();

$quickmarks.each(function(i){
$chScrollPositions[i] = Math.round($(this).offset().top - $('.tile__list').offset().top) - 8;
});

$quickmarks.eq(0).addClass('active');

$('button').click(function(){
var last = $quickmarks.parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active').index();
var next;

switch($(this).index()){
    case 1: 
        next = (last + 4 == $quickmarks.length) ? 0 : last + 4; // Loop around to first
}
$quickmarks.eq(next).addClass('active');
$('.tile_list_wrapper').scrollTo($chScrollPositions[next]);
});
</script>
```

Comment: could you make a fiddle.

Comment: just set up a fiddle...take a look  http://jsfiddle.net/fubjL/ each button triggers both boxes to scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `$('.tile_list_wrapper').scrollTo($chScrollPositions[next]);` will select all items with a class of tile_list_wrapper

Change it to:

```
var $thisTile = $(this).siblings('.tile_list_wrapper');
$($thisTile).scrollTo($chScrollPositions[next]);
```

Comment: Cool THANK YOU! It's working with that tweak ;) Only one thing I noticed now...it still set the other anchors within the 2nd div to "active". Here's the fiddle where you can see that - http://jsfiddle.net/fubjL/2/ Still new to JS, that's why I'm asking for some help. The official documentation is too hard to understand for a beginner

Comment: To stay in the current tile_list_wrapper change the following line: 
next = (last + 4 == $quickmarks.length) ? 0 : last + 4;  to: next = (last + 4 == $(this).siblings('.tile_list_wrapper').find('a').length) ? 0 : last + 4;

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that doesn't do the job yet :-/  My thought was that this `var $quickmarks = $('.tile__list').children('a');` must be defined more specific, but not sure. Isn't this var `var last = $quickmarks.parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active').index();` also applying to all elements? Guys JS is confusing me x-D

Comment: Edited [http://jsfiddle.net/fubjL/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/fubjL/8/) You were right it needed breaking down into the separate elements

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much for your help! The last fiddle works great!